# what the author of nedtries means by "in-place"?

Tags: c, binary-tree, bit-manipulation, trie, patricia-trie

I. Just implemented a kind of bitwise trie (based on nedtries), but my code does lot
Of memory allocation (for each node).
 Contrary to my implemetation, nedtries are claimed to be fast , among othet things,
Because of their small number of memory allocation (if any).
The author claim his implementation to be "in-place", but what does it really means in this context ?
And how does nedtries achieve such a small number of dynamic memory allocation ?

Ps: I know that the sources are available, but the code is pretty hard to follow and I cannot figure how it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look at the nedtrie.h source code.
It seems that the reason it is "in-place" is that **you** have to add the trie bookkeeping data to the items that you want to store.

You use the NEDTRIE_ENTRY macro to add parent/child/next/prev links to your data structure, and you can then pass that data structure to the various trie routines, which will extract and use those added members.

So it is "in-place" in the sense that you augment your existing data structures and the trie code piggybacks on that.

At least that's what it looks like. There's lots of macro goodness in that code so I could have gotten myself confused (:

Comment: So, it works just like Linux kernel's linked list implementation. Thx for having decrypted the code, I had hard time trying to figure out what all these macros did.

Comment: Yes, that's commonly referred to as an "intrusive" linked list.

Answer (score 10):

I'm the author, so this is for the benefit of the many according to Google who are similarly having difficulties in using nedtries. I would like to thank the people here on stackflow for not making unpleasant comments about me personally which some other discussions about nedtries do.

1. I am afraid I don't understand the difficulties with knowing how to use it. Usage is exceptionally easy - simply copy the example in the Readme.html file:

```
typedef struct foo_s foo_t;
struct foo_s {
  NEDTRIE_ENTRY(foo_t) link;
  size_t key;
};
typedef struct foo_tree_s foo_tree_t;
NEDTRIE_HEAD(foo_tree_s, foo_t);
static foo_tree_t footree;
```

static size_t fookeyfunct(const foo_t *RESTRICT r)
{
  return r->key;
}

NEDTRIE_GENERATE(static, foo_tree_s, foo_s, link, fookeyfunct, NEDTRIE_NOBBLEZEROS(foo_tree_s));

int main(void)
{
  foo_t a, b, c, *r;
  NEDTRIE_INIT(&footree);
  a.key=2;
  NEDTRIE_INSERT(foo_tree_s, &footree, &a);
  b.key=6;
  NEDTRIE_INSERT(foo_tree_s, &footree, &b);
  r=NEDTRIE_FIND(foo_tree_s, &footree, &b);
  assert(r==&b);
  c.key=5;
  r=NEDTRIE_NFIND(foo_tree_s, &footree, &c);
  assert(r==&b); /* NFIND finds next largest. Invert the key function to invert this */
  NEDTRIE_REMOVE(foo_tree_s, &footree, &a);
  NEDTRIE_FOREACH(r, foo_tree_s, &footree)
  {
    printf("%p, %u\n", r, r->key);
  }
  NEDTRIE_PREV(foo_tree_s, &footree, &a);
  return 0;
}

You declare your item type - here it's struct foo_s. You need the NEDTRIE_ENTRY() inside it otherwise it can contain whatever you like. You also need a key generating function. Other than that, it's pretty boilerplate.

I wouldn't have chosen this system of macro based initialisation myself! But it's for compatibility with the BSD rbtree.h so nedtries is very easy to swap in to anything using BSD rbtree.h.

1. Regarding my usage of "in place"
   algorithms, well I guess my lack of
   computer science training shows
   here. What I would call "in place"
   is when you only use the memory
   passed into a piece of code, so if
   you hand 64 bytes to an in place
   algorithm it will only touch that 64
   bytes i.e. it won't make use of
   extra metadata, or allocate some
   extra memory, or indeed write to
   global state. A good example is an
   "in place" sort implementation where
   only the collection being sorted
   (and I suppose the thread stack)
   gets touched.

   Hence no, nedtries doesn't need a
   memory allocator. It stores all the
   data it needs in the NEDTRIE_ENTRY
   and NEDTRIE_HEAD macro expansions.
   In other words, when you allocate
   your struct foo_s, you do all the
   memory allocation for nedtries.
2. Regarding understanding the "macro
   goodness", it's far easier to
   understand the logic if you compile
   it as C++ and then debug it :). The
   C++ build uses templates and the
   debugger will cleanly show you state
   at any given time. In fact, all
   debugging from my end happens in a
   C++ build and I meticulously
   transcribe the C++ changes into
   macroised C.
3. Lastly, before a new release, I
   search Google for people having
   problems with my software to see if
   I can fix things and I am typically
   amazed what someone people say about
   me and my free software. Firstly,
   why didn't those people having
   difficulties ask me directly for
   help? If I know that there is
   something wrong with the docs, then
   I can fix them - equally, asking on
   stackoverflow doesn't let me know
   immediately that there is a docs
   problem bur rather relies on me to
   find it next release. So all I would
   say is that if anyone finds a
   problem with my docs, please do
   email me and say so, even if there
   is a discussion say like here on
   stackflow.

Niall

Comment: I just wanted to point out the "in place" is pretty ambiguous terminology.  I think the term people are looking for here is "Intrusive" which is pretty unambiguous and which I've seen used with many other data structures that expect their book keeping pointers to be allocated inside their data.

Comment: Point taken. I've also noticed that different parts of the world like to use different nomenclature for various things. Also, engineers aged different ages and of different generations also have particular preferences for what to call things.

Answer (score 4):

*In-place* means you operate on the original (input) data, so the input data becomes the output data. *Not-in-place* means that you have separate input and output data, and the input data is not modified. *In-place* operations have a number of advantages - smaller cache/memory footprint, lower memory bandwidth, hence typically better performance, etc, but they have the disadvantage that they are destructive, i.e. you lose the original input data (which may or may not matter, depending on the use case).

Comment: Your definition correspond to what I mean by "in-place", but it seems like the auhtor of nedtries has a slighly different one; in his presentation of nedtries he says "nedtries uses an in-place algorithm i.e. it does NOT use dynamic memory". Plus, there is no malloc/calloc/mmap call in his code. How is this possible ?  Here is the link to his page : http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedtries/

Answer (score -1):

In-place means to operate on the input data and (possibly) update it. The implication is that there no copying and/moving of the input data. This may result in loosing the input data original values which you will need to consider if it is relevant for your particular case.